# How do I convert the current user email address to a string in Outlook using C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have created a custom VSTO plugin in Outlook 2016 that asks the user to attach a file, the file is then added to an e-mail reply and automatically sent.

```
public void Attachment_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
            if (explorer != null)
            {
                Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection;
                if (selection.Count >= 1)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = selection[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
                    OpenFileDialog attachment = new OpenFileDialog();
                    attachment.Title = "Add your file";
                    attachment.ShowDialog();

                    if (mailItem != null) //could be something other than MailItem
                    {
                        Outlook.MailItem response = mailItem.ReplyAll();
                        bool retValue = false;
                        response.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                        response.HTMLBody = "<p>MESSAGE</p>" + response.HTMLBody;
                        response.Attachments.Add(attachment.FileName, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1,"Attachment.pdf");
                        response.Send();
                        mailItem.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am attempting to tweak the code so it automatically adds a different attachment depending on the user logged in to Outlook, e.g. if user=user1@company.com add '\fileshare\file1.pdf', if user=user2@company.com add '\fileshare\file2.pdf'

Is this possible?

I am attempting to convert the current user address to string using the below but not had any success:

```
{
 return 
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `selection[1]` selects the *second* item and your count-check is fine with just one item ...

Comment: "not had any success" - did you get any error? Please specify. You are chaining a lot of properties and methods, are you sure none return a null?

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing - all collections in Outlook are 1 based, not 0. Selection[1] will return the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail if there is no active explorer, but you really do not need it.
Off the top of my head:

```
AddressEntry cu = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
ExchangeUser eu = cu.GetExchangeUser();
return (eu == null) ? cu.Address : eu.PrimarySmtpAddress;
```